# Can't mount mount vmfs disk in debian 6 using vmfs-fuse, VMFS unsupported version 5

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi, vmfs

I have a problem with my server. I recently replaced ESXi for Linux Debian,
and i want to mount my second disk on my debian installation using vmfs-fuse.
I already installed the vmfs-fuse package, and tested is but did not work.
I'm trying to mount a physical disk which was the second datastore of ESXi into debian.
Except when I try to mount it as following:

*note: i'm already logged in as root user.*

```
vmfs-fuse /dev/sdb1/ /mnt/fs
```

When i press enter i get the following error:

```
vmfs unsupported version 5
```

I've searched on google, but didn't find any results...
I hope someone can help me with this problem, because there is some data on that disk that I need.
Thanks in advance,
Dean

Answer (score 2):

Your installed vmfs-fuse/vmfs-tools, but the version you've installed does not support VMFS version 5, the version native to ESXi 5. There's some limited support in an [advanced build of vmfs-tools](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=2194), but it's probably not the version of the software you installed.

Can you report the version of vmfs-tools you installed?